# uploading HEX data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am uploading HEX data to MySQL database.

```
$sql= "INSERT into MyTable VALUES ($date,$data)";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed". mysqli_error($con);
}
```

here `$data` is HEX data, that data has `27` which is equivalent to ' in ASCII. so  I am getting an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'xxxxxxxxxx' at line 1.

how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Typically the problem that's so much easier to solve with [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the apostrophe in the string, try reading this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php

Answer (score 3):

Look into [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to secure your queries. Your problem is that you are dumping raw data straight into the SQL. It's not only causing you errors, but it is also [*incredibly* insecure](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 2):

Put a single quotes around variables

```
$sql= "INSERT into loco54321 VALUES ('$date','$data')";<br>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the column in the table into which u are trying to enter the data

```
    INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
    VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Comment: This is not necessary if all columns are specified in the list of values. Including the primary key. We can't say if this has been done in this case.